# GoLang: net.LookupHost returns duplicate ips

Tags: go, networking

I'm trying to run net.LookupHost to get ip address of the machine on which my code is running. It is working on most of the machines but on few machines, it is returning a slice with two entries: Correct ip and a duplicate entry with the same IP.

I tried running nslookup on the host and it is only returning one entry.

Adding the code to the question -

```
    hostname, _ := os.Hostname()

    ips, err := net.LookupHost(hostname)

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%d\n", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Hello, 世界 %#v \n", ips)

    ips2, err := net.LookupIP(hostname)

    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%d\n", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Hello, 世界 %#v \n", ips2)
```

I expected net.LookupHost to only give one entry in the response but it is giving two identical entries in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a DNS resolution issue.
If it is working from other servers then try checking out the file `/etc/hosts`.

> The system consults the /etc/hosts file first, then DNS servers.

source: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.hostname-name-service.html